# Publishing is skipped

Tags: publishing

When publishing is performed, the following message is recorded in the publishing log and publishing is not performed.

```
Publish Item: Name=Home, Uri=sitecore://master/{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}?lang=ja-JP&ver=1, Operation=None, ChildAction=Skip, Explanation=Target item should be deleted, but was not found. Item id: {110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}, database: stage
```

Looking at the stage database, there is no `{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}`.

I would like to publish `{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}` to the stage database.

What kind of correspondence will it be to publish again?

Comment: Are you using Sitecore publish functionality? If yes you can click on this item "{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}" ,then select staging target and publish it with subitems and related items

Comment: What kind of publish are you doing?, the GUID {110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9} is from the out of the box: /sitecore/content/Home item? is your staging publish target with "Preview publishing target" enable?

Comment: I'm sorry. I wrote in the answer.

thank you for your answer.
Yes. I started republishing from the content editor's publish menu.

There is a stage publishing target.
I have published to Stage Database many times in the past (incremental, smart, all republish) and there was no problem.

I did an operation that seems to be related.
A lot of content has been deleted because of publishing restrictions on the site TOP. I wanted to stop publishing and restarted IIS.
After that I got this error.

Comment: If you have publishing restrictions above the published item, they will prevent children from being published, too. Try removing the publishing restrictions and publishing again.

Answer (score 0):

Martin has a really good blog post outlining a number of things to check here: http://blog.martinmiles.net/post/item-not-published-troubleshooting

In summary the key things to check are:

1. check the items workflow state
2. check the items (and parent items) publishing restrictions
3. check you are publishing the correct version
4. check security / permissions

Comment: I'm sorry.
The reason was that only the web was specified as the target in the publishing restriction.
Thank you very much.

Comment: No worries glad this was useful and you solved your issue